# Laravel ffmpeg encoding failed not converting

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert my video using FFmpeg, but I'm getting an error message saying that the encoding failed. I'm not sure if the way I coded it might be wrong. I will just like someone to take a look at my code to see if I might have done something wrong. Here is my code

```
    $viddy=new Video;


        if($request->video){
            $my_video = $request->file('video');
          $video_name = uniqid().$my_video->getClientOriginalName();

     $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => "C:/Users/jayjay/Desktop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
    'ffprobe.binaries' => "C:/Users/jayjay/Desktop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"
]);



        $videoName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($video_name);

$video = $ffmpeg->open($videoName);


$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
                         $format->setAudioCodec("libmp3lame");
                         $format->setKiloBitrate(150);

                         //Save format to amasonS3
$video->save($format, Storage::disk('s3')->url('newvideo.mp4'));

        //Put the new video format in the database
          $viddy->video = $video;
        }

                $viddy->save();
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase  Yes, this is what it says  FFMpeg \ Exception \ RuntimeException
Encoding failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel FFMPEG Error Encoding Failed using Laravel Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767711/laravel-ffmpeg-error-encoding-failed-using-laravel-queue)

Comment: @LuckySaini Not really what I am looking for it kind of looks similar but its not

Comment: Try changing `$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();` to `$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac');`. I faced a similar issue a few months ago. https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/issues/85

Comment: @JPark it didn't work I have a question when it gives me that message saying encoding failed does that mean I downloaded everything correctly? Am I almost there?

Comment: The encoding failed error isn't really descriptive about what exactly the error could be, could be anything, Check to make sure you have the correct ffmpeg version. Might also help to try setting the bitrate to a power of 2 (e.g. 128 rather than 150). Another thing to check is if the `$videoName` is a type of video that ffmpeg can decode. If not, you may need to install an additional codec.

Comment: @JPark what version of ffmpeg should I be using then? I changed the ffmpeg version for my computer to 4.0.2 before I had the latest version then I switched and also the laravel ffmpeg I downloaded was from here https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg. I dont get it. What version of ffmpeg do you have?

Comment: I am running version 3.3.4

Comment: Your best bet is to run the command in debug mode try and get more info on what is causing the problem. With that package, I believe you can use `->addFilter(['-loglevel', 'debug'])`. Or, instead, execute the command in your console with the `-loglevel debug` flag.

Comment: @JPark it seems to be working. But what I'm trying accomplish here is that I want to save it to s3 and the database but it tells me that FFMpeg\Media\Video could not be converted to string what am I supposed to do?

Comment: @JayJay123 I have added an answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling the `save()` method wrong, which is probably the result of the error. Also, it might make things easier to use the facade with this package when opening the file. Try it like this instead:

```
$video = FFMpegFacade::fromDisk('s3')->open($folder . '/' . $filename)

...

$video->export()->toDisk('s3')->inFormat($format)->save($folder . '/' . $new_filename);
```

To save the video in the database is a different story. If you want to save the raw data of the video, you can serialize and base64 encode, etc. But, since you are storing it to disk, it's usually easier to save the path to the video instead:

```
$viddy->video = $folder . '/' . $new_filename;
$viddy->save();
```

Comment: Thank you. I wished of changed my question to trying to resize the video because I am also trying to resize the video instead of the setting the killobitrate and the audio codec but I constantly get unable to probe and I really don't understand why when I'm actually following the example from https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

Comment: No problem. If my solution worked for your original issue, please mark as correct. If you have a new problem that needs solved, please create a new post separate from this one and I'd be happy to take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay great I'm about to create now Will you be the first to answer? You have such a great help

Comment: Sure, just reply with the link here.