# How to fix error "Encoding Failed" using FFMPEG?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am using `FFMPEG` for converting `mp4` to `m3u8` format on an `Ubuntu` local machine. But I am facing an error `Encoding Failed`.

My controller code is:

```
FFMpeg::open(public_path()."/uploads/".$filename)
    ->exportForHLS()
    ->addFormat($lowBitrate)
    ->addFormat($midBitrate)
    ->addFormat($highBitrate)
    ->toDisk(env('APP_ENV'))
    ->save(public_path().'/converted/adaptive_steve.m3u8');
```

The error is:

[image: Error]

Config file is

[image: Config file]

How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768555/6212294) solves your problem.

Comment: I have also checked all possibilities and but I can not find solutions

Comment: First of all, please share your second image (config file) as literal string like your controller. Second, don't you have to add `->InFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\WHATEVER_FORMAT_IS_CORRECT)` before `->save` ? Read the [documentation](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg), they use that to export it to the desired format...